# page--front.tpl.php being ignore in favour of page--node--page.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I've got an issue which I'm not sure how to address. I've got a specific page that I've set as front page. I've created a custom template for it and named it `page--front.tpl.php` and it was as expected until I've added `page--node--page.tpl.php` which seems to be overriding `page--front.tpl.php`.

Is this the correct and expected behaviour? How can I force it the `page--front.tpl.php` to be used?

I'm using Drupal 7 with and a child of the Bootstrap's theme.

Comment: Don't have time to test for sure, but try implementing `hook_preprocess_page()` and re-ordering the `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']` array into something that suits you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have a custom theme for nodes, try to do this using `THEME_preprocess_node` as follow

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables){
     $node = $variables['node'];
     if($node->type == "SOME_CONTENT_TYPE")
          $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][]='page__node__SOMETHING';
}
```

Then create `page--node--SOMETHING.tpl.php` in your theme folder. To get the values of the fields you can use the [entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module and do something like the following code (I supposed `field_something` is machine name of one of your fields):

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables){
     $node = $variables['node'];
     if($node->type == "ANY_CONTENT_TYPE"){
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][]='page__node__SOMETHING';
        $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$variables['node']);
        $variables['title'] = $wrapper->title->value();
        $variables['something'] = $wrapper->field_something->value();
     } 
}
```

By this code `$title` and `$something` variables are available in  `page--node--SOMETHING.tpl.php` file.

Comment: That didn't quite work. It put `page--front.tpl.php` inside my `page--node--page.tpl.php`

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Did you remove page--node--page.tpl.php? Put the code of front page in the question

Comment: Yep, I did, using it `drush`

Comment: Like I said put your `page--front.tpl.php` and `template.php` code in here